# Deal with same method body in different handlers

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a method fired on mouse down:

```
private function setGender(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            check.visible = true;
            check.x = e.target.x;
            check.y = e.target.y;
        }
```

**The same method body is shared by another method fired on a keyboard Event** (so, it takes a keyboard Event for argument). Which is the best way to deal with situations like this one? I would like to have only one method!

One way could be to create a new method called by the two event handlers (even if, if I need to use e.target, it can change according to the type of event and other variables, so I should eventually create a method that takes e.target as a parameter). This creates three methods...

Would it be possible to change for example e:MouseEvent with a parent of MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent? Would it work? Any drawbacks? Is this totally wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last sentence is on the right track, but not quite correct. What you actually want is an Event type that is **higher** in the hierarchical structure than both `MouseEvent` and `KeyboardEvent`. This means an `Event` is actually what you'd like to use.

```
private function setGender(e:Event):void
        {
            check.visible = true;
            check.x = e.target.x;
            check.y = e.target.y;
        }
```

As a base `Event` has the only property you're looking for in both events, this should work. If, however, you want to use a different property, *even one shared by MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent*, you can only use it if it exists in the base Event class. However, you can also try casting the event if you end up wanting to use other properties of the events.

```
private function setGender(e:Event):void
        {
            if (e is MouseEvent)
            {
                //handle mouse
            }
            else
            {
                //handle keyboard
            }
            check.visible = true;
            check.x = e.target.x;
            check.y = e.target.y;
        }
```

Comment: Is this a common practice or I "invented" something new but dangerous?   :-)

Comment: No, that's standard use of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the same event handler for both, but specify the argument type as Event (which is the base class for both event types that you target.) Note that this will of course not work if you are using anything that is specific to KeyboardEvent in the other handler (that you are not showing) but if they are really identical it will work.

```
private function setGender(e : Event) : void
{
    check.visible = true;
    check.x = e.target.x;
    check.y = e.target.y
}
```

This event listener can be used for any event that is dispatched by a display object (or any object with `x` and `y` properties).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you code would be cleaner and better express your intent if you were to make use of the [extract method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring pattern as you originally suggested:

```
private function onMouseEvent(event : MouseEvent) : void { 
    updateGender(event.target);
}

private function onKeyboardEvent(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
    updateGender(event.target); // are you sure event.target is the intended 
                                // DisplayObject on a KeyboardEvent?
}

private function updateGender(target : DisplayObject) : void {
    // update the DisplayList here.
}
```

This way you are providing a decoupling between the trigger (either a MouseEvent or a KeyboardEvent) and the reaction (the code in `updateGender()`).

Comment: The fact it that it adds another method and if in a program you have many situations like this one, you can end up with a lot of code. Don't worry for the event.target of KeyboardEvent, but thanks for pointing all this out.

Comment: I like this answer more than the one that was accepted. When you start type checking (`if (e is MouseEvent)`) you should always think twice. On the other hand, this solution kind of violates the 'Don't Repeat Yourself' (DRY) rule. I reckon that with the AS event system you're always in doubt over which rule you want to violate (DRY vs. separation of concerns). That's why I created a little [library](https://github.com/RIAstar/Protection) to handle this issue. It eliminates the need for those handlers. It's a work in progress and there's no docs whatsoever, but it's usable. [/end selfpromotion]

Comment: No problem for the selfpromotion, even if I will test your library when the docs are ready   :-)   Anyway, in this case, being the bodies of my methods really huge (and there's no way to change them), I preferred not to violate the 'DRY' rule.

Comment: @RIAstar I'm not sure how the code snippet above is a violation of DRY?  If you are reffering to the fact that I call updateGender() twice then I fear you are trying to make things a touch dehydrated!

Comment: @JonnyReeves :-) Okay you're probably right on that one, but this box is too damn small to express my grieves properly. It's also about the fact that the outline of a class is littered with handler functions. They have names that don't say _what_ they do, only _when_ they do it. They have arguments that are ignored 90% of the time. e.g. usually when you click on a button, you don't need any additional information. To do it properly I'd have to write `private function onSubmitButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void { submit(); }`; same pattern over and over again (hence the DRY).